# Azure policy allowing only specific AD groups to create public IP

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying create a custom policy to deny Azure AD groups from creating public IPs except some specific group but I am hit with errors not sure where the issue is coming from.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "field": "owner",
          "in": "[parameters('alloweGroupsID')]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
    "details": {
      "roleDefinitionIds": [
        "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/4d97b98b-1d4f-4787-a291-c67834d212e7"
      ],
      "conflictEffect": "audit",
      "operations": [
        {
          "operation": "addOrReplace",
          "field": ["Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"],
          "value": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @GordonBy, not sure the RBAC can work because i am using built in role to allow users. but when i tried to enforce the policy i stil got this error - `Error: creating/updating Policy Definition "deny-public-ip-creation": policy.DefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdateAtManagementGroup: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidPolicyRuleEffectDetails" Message="The policy definition 'deny-public-ip-creation' rule is invalid. The policy effect 'details' property could not be parsed."`

Answer (score 0):

Azure Policy is not the right way to enforce a per-user-group restriction.

You should be leveraging [**Azure Role Based Access Control (RBAC)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) to allow authorization based rules. I'd also suggest familiarising yourself with [Deny Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments) .

Comment: Thanks @GordonBy I guess i should do something like this but wondering how to specify the condition for denying ip address write for all groups except one group.  
`
 resource "azurerm_role_definition" "role_assignment_write_delete" {
     name  = "deny IP creation"
     scope = data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id
     description = "Management of role assignments"
    
     permissions {
         actions = [*]
         not_actions = [Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/write]
     }
    
 }
`